# css nested list position absolute

Tags: html, list, sass, css-position, nav

http://jsfiddle.net/jmm3816z/

I have a nested navigation the first level li need to be `position:relative`
 but the children of the list need to use the position of the ul.  in another word it need to be on `top:0` of the level `<ul>` instead of `<li>`
is there a way to do it

```css
    .level1 {
      background: pink;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .level1>li {
        position: relative !important;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 1em;
     }
     .level1>li .level2 {
          background: lightgreen;
          position: absolute;
          left: 100%;
          top: 0;
          display: none;
      }
      .level1>li .level2>li {
            padding: .5em;
      }
```

```html
<ul class="level1">
  <li>position:relative;
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>position:absolute;</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>position:relative;
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>position:absolute;</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why the <li> have to be in position: relative?

Comment: Why do the sub-level `li` need to be `absolute`? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Is it this - http://jsfiddle.net/jmm3816z/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D yes that is what i want to achieve but li need to be relative, @Fabrizio Calderan, b/c I have other position:absolute div inside `li` that need it to anchor.

Comment: Perhaps you need to show us the **full** issue/HTML then.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jmm3816z/2/ here I updated

Comment: is there not an issue with your css? i.e. you don't *seem* to be closing your css rules correctly? (not valid syntax?)

Comment: @jbutler483 the scss syntax is correct. I am trying to achieve that @paulie have but with `position:relative` on the `level1>li`

Comment: @wlin: Sorry, it's just that you've tagged css, and not 'scss', so I jumped to conclusions. Sorry!

Comment: Now I have to ask, why does the div need to be positioned absolutely?

Comment: If you have a pure CSS problem, *only* post the compiled CSS.  Don't post the Sass unless that's part of the problem.

Comment: @Paulie, b/c it is a design element that need place pixel by pixel.

Comment: @cimmanon I compile the scss to css